# Newbie trouble building script for a report

Tags: r

I am a newbie to coding and to R. I have been trying to solve a problem for a report that I am drawing and have hit a wall.
I have spent the last two days trying to find a workable answer and am now at my wit's end.

I have a data frame of student results. The columns are as follows

1. Student Number
2. Academic Year eg 2014, 2015 etc
3. Academic Semester eg Jan or June
4. Qualification eg Qual1, Qual2 etc
5. Modules eg Subject1, subject2 etc. the issue here is that subject1 may be in Qual1 and Qual2 but suject2 may only be in Qual1
6. Result. This is either "Passed" or "FAILED"

I am trying to create a summary/list showing the percentage passed for each module where students were active. Something like this

```
Year Semester Qualification Module    PassRate
2014 Jan      Qual1         Subject1  62.54%
2014 Jan      Qual1         Subject2  72.81%
.
.
.
2014 July     Qual1         Subject1  69.51%
.
.
2014 Jan      Qual2         Subject1  42.86%
2014 Jan      Qual2         Subject3  55.95%
etc.
```

I thought that perhaps an `IF` statement might work but that seems way too cumbersome. I also looked at `For each` but I can't seem to figure how to get it to work or a combination of the above. I have tried `aggregate, count =, cbind` and anything that i could find from my good friend Google.

I have the following code

```
AcademicYears <- as.character(unique(unlist(HE_Stats$Year)))
AcademicYears_count <- NROW(AcademicYears)

AcademicSemesters <- as.character(unique(unlist(HE_Stats$ActualSemester)))
AcademicSemesters_count <- NROW(AcademicSemesters)

Qualifications <- as.character(unique(unlist(HE_Stats$Qualification)))
Qualifications_count <- NROW(Qualifications)

Modules <- as.character(unique(unlist(HE_Stats$ModuleCode)))
Modules_count <- NROW(Modules)

df <- HE_Stats %>% 
group_by(Year,ActualSemester,Qualification, ModuleCode) %>%

aggregate(cbind(count = AcademicSemesters) ~ AcademicYears,
data = HE_Stats,
FUN = function(AcademicSemesters){NROW(AcademicSemesters)})
```

the result of this is that it shows me one semester per year. My latest plan is to build the matrix column by column.

Comment: please privode some sample data using `dput`, ans the corresponing desired output..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could supply sample data would be able to give you a better answer. But say that your data looked something like (this solution uses the dplyr package:

library(dplyr)

```
data <- tibble(student_number = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
           academic_year = c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015),
           semester = c("jan", "jan", "jan","jan", "june", "june"),
           qualification = c("qual1", "qual2", "qual1", "qual1", "qual2",
                             "qual2"),
           module = c("subject1", "subject1", "subject1", "subject1", 
                       "subject2", "subject2"),
           result = c("passed", "failed", "passed", "passed", "passed", 
                      "failed"))

# A tibble: 6 x 6
  student_number academic_year semester qualification module   result  
           <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>    <chr>         <chr>    <chr> 
1              1          2014 jan      qual1         subject1 passed
2              2          2014 jan      qual2         subject1 failed
3              3          2014 jan      qual1         subject1 passed
4              4          2015 jan      qual1         subject1 passed
5              5          2015 june     qual2         subject2 passed
6              6          2015 june     qual2         subject2 failed
```

First I would make a logical vector of whether the subject had passed:

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(pass = ifelse(result == "passed", TRUE, FALSE))
```

Then summarise the grouped data:

```
data %>%
  group_by(academic_year, semester, qualification, module) %>%
  summarise(
    pass_rate = (sum(pass)/n())*100
  )
```

To produce:

```
  academic_year semester qualification module   pass_rate
          <dbl> <chr>    <chr>         <chr>        <dbl>
1          2014 jan      qual1         subject1       100
2          2014 jan      qual2         subject1         0
3          2015 jan      qual1         subject1       100
4          2015 june     qual2         subject2        50
```